# JSON EXtraction in Python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to extract a specific part of the JSON but I keep on getting errors.

I am interested in the following sections:

```
"field": "tag",
"value": "Wian",
```

---

I can extract the entire filter section using:

```
for i in range(0,values_num):
    dedata[i]['filter']
```

But if I try to filter beyond that point I just get errors.

Could someone please assist me with this?

---

Here is the JSON output style:

```
{
  "mod_time": 1594631137499,
  "description": "",
  "id": 82,
  "name": "Wian",
  "include_custom_devices": true,
  "dynamic": true,
  "field": null,
  "value": null,
  "filter": {
    "rules": [
      {
        "field": "tag",
        "operand": {
          "value": "Wian",
          "is_regex": false
        },
        "operator": "~"
      }
    ],
    "operator": "and"
  }
}
```

Comment: "I just get errors"- what errors? What code produces these errors?

Comment: Here there is a good [tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-json/) about Json handling in python. Maybe this will help u.

Comment: you can use `dedata[i]['filter']['rules'][0]['field']` and `dedata[i]['filter']['rules'][0]['operand']['value']`

Comment: If I try to add anything beyond the filter portion, I get a key error. I did some reading on this error but nothing that helped. @ForceBru

Comment: @deadshot thanks for assisting, but it still gives a key error: 
" KeyError: 'rules' "

Comment: can you post the error and clarify you have list of json objects or single json object you posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably trying to access the data in rules but since its an array, you have to specifically access that array by getting the [0] index.

You could simplistically just use `.get('<name>')` as shown below:

`dedata['filter']['rules'][0].get('field'))`

Likewise for value:

`dedata[i]['filter']['rules'][0]['operand'].get('value')`

comment out the for loop and try without it and `[i]` and see if it works